# select * like with masked compare

Tags: php, mysqli

I must search thru DB for like `$string`s. A '?' in the reference String represents any character, so this character must be disregarded but all the others must match.

The reference `$string ='abcd?efg'` would match `$stringb ='abcdXefg'` or `$stringc = 'abcd1efg'`. How does the mySQL "Select..." look like?

```
$string = 'abcd?efg';    
$row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE String LIKE '$string'");
$result = $row->fetch_assoc();
print_r( json_encode($result) );
```

Comment: Are you looking for regular expressions?

Comment: `$string = 'abcd_efg';`. The `_` is a wildcard for 1  character. I assume 1 character is what you're after. If it's more, use `%`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex like this:

```
$string = 'abcde?efg';
$searchGroup = explode('?', $string);    
$row = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE String REGEXP '^" . $searchGroup[0].".".$searchGroup[1]."$'"); // starts with abcde and ends with efg and allows one character between the groups.
```

This will get one character between the two groups and it can be any characters. From the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/pattern-matching.html):

> “.” matches any single character.

Comment: This will match `abcde` or `efg`, it won't match `abcdeXefg`.

Comment: Ack, you're right @Barmar. I was so focused on the starting and ending points that I skipped that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

The 1-character wildcard in `LIKE` is `_`, so use `str_replace` to replace the `?` with `_`.

```
$like_string = str_replace('?', '_', $string);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE String LIKE ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $like_string);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: It's not working with the Underscore. Could you expand your code-snipe a bit. How would you check if $result is NULL or not? I did it as follows: On the DB there is the reference-string eg. 'abcd_efg'. with the query i enter the string to compare eg.  'abcd1efg' this must match.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you, see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/67e92/1. To tell if the query found anything, check `$stmt->num_rows` -- read the MySQLI documentation for full details.